# Updating specific files with git for django app on heroku

Tags: python, django, git, github, heroku

I deployed my django app to heroku and its working well. When I change something in project on local files and want to push to heroku It always push all files and it takes time.

```
> git add templates/post/detail.html
> git commit -am "read more"

[master 153e38f] read more
2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
> git push heroku master
```

I use these commands. But it's deploying everything:

```
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 695 bytes | 695.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        1392 static files copied to '/tmp/build_57ea00eb/staticfiles', 3734 post-processed.
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 280.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v15
remote:        https://xxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git
   2d9ba8e..153e38f  master -> master
```

The file that I changed around 1mb but it pushes 280mb. So what's the problem with it?

Comment: your app has 280 megabytes not the file. my guess the huge app site comes from "1392 static files copied to '/tmp/build_57ea00eb/staticfiles', 3734 post-processed"  you might have duplicated static files? You could also outsource the files to AWS or a similar service and let Django just take care of the templates and server logic

Comment: Yeah I have "static" and "staticfiles" on my local. But I don't want to push them I just want to push the file that I want to push. Can I ignore static files with gitignore? Here my gitignore: *.pyc
*~
__pycache__
myvenv
db.sqlite3
.DS_Store
media

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to push your static file for every time then run this command :

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Enable static file for future:

```
heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC(for future use).
```